# Angular How to check for overlap values in 2 arrays?

Tags: javascript

I would like to check for overlap values in 2 arrays

**Scenario 1:**

```
cuisineA = [a,b,c];
cuisineB = [a,b,c,d,e,f];
```

will return me a boolean value **isOverlap = true**

**Scenario 2:**

```
cuisineA = [a,b,c];
cuisineB = [d,e,f];
```

will return me a boolean value **isOverlap = false**

Currently my code looks like this

```
const overlapCuisines = this.cuisineA.filter(
      cuisine => this.cuisineB.indexOf(cuisine) < 0
    );
this.isOverlap = overlapCuisines.length > 0;
```

However, when it is in scenario 2, overlapCuisines would contain the value [a,b,c] and hence isOverlap = true when it should be false. How should I code it to display it properly? Appreciate your help!

Comment: Do you want to check partial overlap or full overlap?

Comment: this.isOverlap = overlapCuisines.length > 0 ? true : false;

Comment: Checking for partial overlap if I'm not wrong. CuisineA and cuisineB cannot contain the same values, if it does isOverlap = true. And as long as at least one element is the same in both arrays isOverlap = true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If order of items isn't important, then [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method can be used.

```js
var cuisineA = ["a","b","c"];
var cuisineB = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];

var isOverlap = cuisineA.some(value => cuisineB.includes(value));

console.log(isOverlap);


cuisineA = ["a","b","c"];
cuisineB = ["d","e","f"];

isOverlap = cuisineA.some(value => cuisineB.includes(value));

console.log(isOverlap);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this.

```
const overlapCuisines = this.cuisineA.filter(cuisine => this.cuisineB.indexOf(cuisine) !== -1);
this.isOverlap = overlapCuisines.length > 0 ? true : false;
```

Or

```
this.isOverlap = Boolean(overlapCuisines.length > 0) ;
```

Comment: Upvoted since it pointed out the missing piece in the question, helping not only with the solution, but also with the learning side.
If compatilibty with Internet Explorer is not a requirement, you could also use the `include` method for better readability: `const overlapCuisines = cuisineA.filter(cuisine => cuisineB.includes(cuisine));`

Answer (score 1):

Use set intersection

```
let isOverlap = !!((new Set(A)).intersection(new Set(B)))
```

Note: this is pseudocode